# Reverse Engineer SQL2008 Database to Diagram

Tags: sql-server-2008, reverse-engineering, diagram

Visio 2007 support reverse engineering a MSSQL Database. However, SQL2008 is not supported ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92811/reverse-engineering-for-database-diagramming-in-visio-with-sql-server-2008/583227)).

Are there other (free?) tools that can do this?

thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL Server Management Studio Tool can do it.

1. Attach the DB
2. Expand its node
3. Right click Database Diagrams -> New Database Diagram

N.B: You'll need to be logged in as a dbo and have the database diagramming components installed (Management studio will tell you if not)

Answer (score -1):

[DeZign for Databases](http://www.datanamic.com/dezign/index.html) can import SQL2008 databases (you can use the 2005 driver, that works)

Comment: He asked for a free one!