# Import a ER diagram in Gliffy

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-relationship, visio, gliffy

I have a SQL Database. I would create an ER diagram in Gliffy ([site](http://www.gliffy.com/index-h.php)). Gliffy only imports files from Microsoft Visio. So I don't how to export my DB from SQL Server in Visio to create the diagram there and importing the same into Gliffy.

Any ideas? There are other tools I can use to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visio professional (except Visio 2013) has a "reverse engineer" feature. You can use it to create a diagram of your existing SQL Server database. See here for example:

[Reverse engineering an existing database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/reverse-engineering-an-existing-database-HA001182257.aspx)

[Reverse and forward engineering databases in Visio 2010](http://www.ingmarverheij.com/reverse-and-forward-engineering-databases-in-visio-2010)

Comment: I'm trying with visio professional... The second link don't work for me. The plugin is not working with Win7 32 bit. There's a workaround, but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Here is the link to official docs for 2010: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/reverse-engineer-an-existing-database-into-a-database-model-HA101818235.aspx. 

You may be facing a known problem with SQL SERVER 2008, please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92811/reverse-engineering-for-database-diagramming-in-visio-with-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

First import the SQL schema from DB to Visio. Then export the file and import in Gliffy.

That's all.

Comment: From Visio to Gliffy I can only export/import an image file... i thinked I can export a file editable from Gliffy...